# Brew Memcached error: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed on brew php70

Tags: laravel-5, memcached, homebrew

When using the `Cache` facade to save a query I get the error:

```
Exception in MemcachedStore.php line 85:
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

This only happens on a mac with php70 installed (with memcached). On any other machine this works fine with the same data. It only happens when I try to save query output (collections).

In phpinfo the memcached module does show and with the serializer igbinary like the others.

Just to elaborate, the code is fine, nothing special. I'm guessing it's more of a settings or versions problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the problem.

In my class I have an (it's public, but makes no difference if it's protected or private, the result is the same) array which controls some things for that class. In that array there are anonymous functions.

Now php 5.6 does not store the variable when putting it in the cache system, but for some reason php 7 does.

So now I know.